# Skip last K lines while traversing a file

Tags: c++

A user had posted a similar question earlier this day which was very soon closed due to its vagueness. Thus re-posting the question in detail with a solution as I didn't find a specific article dealing with it on the internet.

The requirement is to read and print all lines of a file except the last K.

Suppose a file contains text as:

```
Hello there!
My name is
Mr. XYZ
I like playing football
```

And if K is 2, then it should print all the lines except the last 2. i.e.:

```
Hello there!
My name is
```

Comment: may i PLEASE know the reason for downvote? is it that bad question?

Comment: "the question was closed due to its vagueness. Thus re-posting". Why are you surprised at the downvotes? Giving the answer to the question does not make the question any better.

Comment: @Borgleader I think the earlier question was not clear at all but this is

Comment: Also, IIRC the close reason was not "unclear what you're asking" but "minimal understanding of the problem being solved". Which is still the case here, imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply put lines into a `std::deque` and dump one element when its size is greater `k` ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<deque>


int main()
{
    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open("output.txt",std::ios::in);
    std::deque<std::string> deq;
    std::string str;
    int k=2;
    while(std::getline(fs,str))
    {
            deq.push_back(str);
            if(deq.size() > k)
            {
              std::cout <<deq.front()<<std::endl;
              deq.pop_front();
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be solved by creating a window of size K and then traversing the file till the right end of the window reaches the end of the file. The basic steps being:

1. Traverse the first K lines of the file without printing it.
2. Open the same file using another stream object.
3. Now simultaneously traverse both the streams so that fisrt stream is always K lines ahead of the second stream.
4. Run a loop while the second first stream is valid. In the loop, read through the first stream as well and keep print the lines.

The code would be

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
int main()
{
    fstream fs;
    fs.open("abc.txt",ios::in);
    string str;
    int K = 2;
    while(getline(fs,str) && K>1)
    {
        K--;
    }
    if(K==1)
    {
        fstream fsNew;
        fsNew.open("abc.txt",ios::in);
        while(getline(fs,str))
        {
            getline(fsNew,str);
            cout<<str;
        }
    }
    cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: Somewhat inefficient if the file is quite long, and the number to skip is big enough to not fit in the file-cache... You only need to read the file once if you store the lines in a buffer of K lines [and as long as K is reasonable, that is probably the better approach].